# Webmin администрирование

Tags: ubuntu

Для устройства общего доступа к Интернету установил AltLinux Ковчег. Вся остальная сеть на Windows разных версий.Общий доступ работает, но не могу разобраться, как ограничить права, скорость, объем скачивания некоторых пользователей. По совету коллеги из другого Департамента на другую машину поставил Ubuntu 10 и Webmin. Коллега говорил, что это проще для "виндусятника". Вопрос: где взять хорошее руководство по администрированию Webmin?Спасибо.

Comment: Нашел руководство в Интернете. Буду штудировать. Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вы путаете разные вещи.
Для контроля траффика windows-сети с помощью шлюза на linux необходимы соответсвующие пакеты + настройки на шлюзе.
web-траффик можно контролировать (ограничивать, выделять объем) с помощью sqiud (это прокси-сервер).  Можно сделать как прозрачным для пользователя, так и с авторизацией.
сам шлюз строим на политиках iptabes (я предпочитаю настраивать его через shorewall).webmin - это всего лишь web-интерфейс для управления системой (в данном случае Вашим шлюзом), ее настройками и т.п.
Описаний подобных примеров (с настройками) вагон и маленькая тележка... Главное - уяснить что Вы хотите - т.е. сформировать для себя ТЗ.

Answer (score 0):

WEBMIN всего лишь удобный вебовский интерфейс к Вашей убунту, чтобы управлять трафиком нужно ставить прогу для этого например сквиду